# Vuex getter при получении по id возвращает саму функцию?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

есть стейт

```
state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Первый текст', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: 'Второй текст', done: false }
    ],
},
```

есть геттер

```
getters: {
    GET_TODO: (state) => (id) => {  
      return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    }
  }
```

когда пытаюсь получить строку по id

```
mounted () {
    this.todo = this.GET_TODO(1)
    console.log(this.todo)
  },
```

в консоль выдает эту функцию а не строку с id = 1. Вопрос почему?

Answer (score 0):

Я не спец в javascript но похоже что конструкция

```
GET_TODO: (state) => (id) => {  
  return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
}
```

Равносильна этой

```
GET_TODO: function name1(state) {
    return function name2(id) {
        return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id);
    }
}
```

Поэтому вызов `this.GET_TODO(1)` и возвращает функцию

Comment: то есть надо так во vuex функцию переписать?

Comment: ааа типа он вернул ее на  => (id)  вот этом моменте!

Comment: надо геттер изменить, возможно там state другим способом можно получить. Из this например. Или тебе надо где-то его засетить Тут уже не скажу.

Comment: getter взял из официальной документации! Вобщем надо понять как параметр id передать в геттер.

Comment: эмммм, ` (state, id) => {...}

Comment: "Стиль обращения как к свойствам" https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html

Comment: Да так пробовал, функция выдает - undefined.
А console.log(id) - выдает весь state почему то?
То есть id нифига не передался почему то

Comment: И я так понимаю обращение как к свойствам это только внутри state работа. Типа геттер передаешь в другой геттер и с ним работаешь. А тут надо из вне по id получить инфу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что говорит официальная документация!
**Стиль обращения как к методам**
Можно также передавать аргументы геттерам, возвращая функцию. Это например пригодится, когда необходимо возвращать массив по указанному критерию:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: state => id => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id);
  }
}

store.getters.getTodoById(2); // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

Обратите внимание, что геттеры, доступ к которым выполняется как к методам, будут запускаться каждый раз при их вызове, а результаты не будут кэшироваться.

Comment: Вроде все так же сделано)

Answer (score 0):

Фрагменты вашего кода правильные. Вы не указали как вы подключаете `getters` в ваш компонент(приложение), но если вы используете [вспомогательную функцию](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters) `mapGetters` - значит "проксируете " геттеры хранилища в локальные вычисляемые свойства компонента, все должно работать.

```
// импортируете mapGetters из vuex 
const {
  mapGetters
} = Vuex

// используете в computed 
...mapGetters(['GET_TODO'])
```

Если вы не хотите использовать `mapGetters`, можете использовать синтаксис прямого доступа к геттерам:

```
  $store.getters['GET_TODO'](2)
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Первый текст', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: 'Второй текст', done: false }
    ],
  },
  getters: {
    GET_TODO: (state) => (id) => {  
      return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    }
  },
})
const {
  mapGetters
} = Vuex

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      todo: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['GET_TODO'])
  },
  mounted () {
    this.todo = this.GET_TODO(1)
    console.log(this.todo)
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ todo }}
  <hr>
  {{ $store.getters['GET_TODO'](2)}}
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))) Действительно проблема была что я объявлял ...mapGetters(['GET_TODO']) в methods а надо было в computed. Глубину вопроса я конечно не понял почему геттерс в вычисляемых свойствах ? но код работает всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Тут вы создаете геттер, который возвращает тоже функцию `(state) => (id) => { // тут какая-то логика }` (данная конструкция состоит из двух функций, первая вернет сам геттер например в [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters), что создаст [замыкание](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure) аргумента `state` (кстати тут можно воспользоваться [деструктуризацией](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring): `({ todos }) => ...`), затем полученную функцию вы можете вызвать с параметром `id` в своем темплейте/логике компонента):

```js
getters: {
  GET_TODO: ({ todos }) => (id) => todos.find((todo) => todo.id === id) || {},
}
```

То есть далее вам необходимо воспользоваться к примеру [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters).

```js
computed: {
  // и уже далее вы можете использовать вызов GET_TODO(id)
  ...mapGetters('GET_TODO'),
},
```

Тут стоит заметить, что так использовать геттеры нужно аккуратно, потому что вы теряете основное удобство геттера - это кэширование. Вот статья с [советами работы с vuex](https://habr.com/ru/post/459034/).